# How can I use remember() method in Laravel to cache the query using query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an application that is written using Laravel 5.2.

In many cases I am using query builder to build my queries like so

```
DB::connection('custom')->table('user')
->join
.....
->where(
........->get();
```

How can I use the method `remember()` to cache the query generated from the query builder?

I tried to use `->remember(60)` just before `get()` but this is giving me an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::remember()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should do this

```
 $value = Cache::remember('users', 60, function()
  {
     return DB::table('users')->get();
 });
```

Comment: I think 'users' is a key for the cache, right? if so should that be unique somehow to the query for identical retrieval ?

Comment: it deppends, change the users before , 60 ... append an id or time or whatever suites your case

Comment: Since I am generating from a query builder. Isn't there a way to use the actual query with the binding values as a key? The method toSql does not include the bonded values

Comment: @Jaylen Use different keys for different queries. Maybe ''users.all-users' for a query retrieving all users and 'users.verified-users' for retrieving verified users. You only need to append an id if the data is in some way unique or restricted to one user for a particular query. Do not use time for that purpose, unless you're storing the time used for the key through some other method since you won't be able to retrieve the cache otherwise.